# Swipe through list items in detail of each item - Flutter

Tags: flutter, hybrid-mobile-app, flutter-animation

I have rendered a list of items on a page. I can tap the item to view its detail, How do I swipe left and right in the list item detail to go to the next item detail. Attaching images for more explanation.

[This is the main list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAE1I.png)

[This is item detail on tap of list item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/On3NJ.png)

What I want is to go to the next item in the list by swiping through the list detail.

Comment: Perhaps put the detail page in a GestureDetector and look for a swipe gesture?  (Or even perhaps use a PageView?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jon Mountjoy is right, just use PageView in detail page, page view items is your list items, when you click the item in the list view, pass index and in next detail page view page, jump to that index item or assign the initial index of controller to that selected index.